# In python why does my instance variable change after being referred to in a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following code, why does the vector instance `a` change after `a.add(b)`?

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        # assign to a var
        self._vector = arg

    def add(self, arg):
        result_vector = self._vector

        # add elements
        for i in range(len(arg._vector)):
            result_vector[i] += arg._vector[i]

        return result_vector

    def print(self):
        print(self._vector)

a = Vector([1, 2, 3])
b = Vector([3, 4, 5])

a.print()
b.print()

print(a.add(b))

a.print()
b.print()
```

I was expecting `result_vector` to contain the addition but that `a` would retain its own value.

E.g. running this code outputs

```
[1, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 6, 8] 
[4, 6, 8] # <--- why has a changed?
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `result_vector = self._vector` - this does **not** create a copy. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/3001761.

Comment: You added stuff to `result_vector`, which is the same list as `self._vector`.

Comment: Could you please add a plain python tag?

Comment: @MadPhysicist done